# Which should I prefer IEnumerable vs List for LINQ Expressions on IRepository

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, interface, repository

I want to return a whole list as LINQ for a product based project. I have questions about which one I use in IRepository will be more effective or correct.

```
Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllProducts();
```

Normally I used something like this.

```
IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllProducts();
```

What is the difference between these two types?

Comment: it's not a question about *performance*, but about *semantics*. `IEnumerable` is just another *interface*, it makes no guarantees about the underlying data. It might be a materialized list, it might however also be an infinite feed. If the former, there's absoluteley no difference in performance.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain: I think OP doesn't know `Task<T>`, so its not about the difference between IEnumerable and List but about using a task or not.